# How to return a const char * from a C/C++ function?

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, char

I have the following C++ function that reads a string from the flash memory and returns it.
I want to avoid using the String class because this is on an Arduino and I've been advised that the String class for the Arduino is [buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60874852/1742777).

```
const char* readFromFlashMemory()
{
    char s[FLASH_STOP_ADDR-FLASH_START_ADDR+2];
    memset(s, (byte)'\0', FLASH_STOP_ADDR-FLASH_START_ADDR+2);
    unsigned short int numChars = 0;

    for (int i = FLASH_START_ADDRESS; i <= FLASH_STOP_ADDRESS; i++)
    {
        byte b = EEPROM.read(i);
        if (b == (byte)'\0')
            return s;
        else
            s[numChars++] = (char)b;
    }
}
```

This function seems to work. But the calling method gets back an empty string.
Am I not allowed to return a pointer to a character array that is on this function's stack?
How is the best/most idiomatic way I should write this function so the calling function receives the value that I want to pass to it?

Comment: There's a ton of questions like this on Stack Overflow.  Basically "why can't I return a pointer to a local variable" or "how to get around said issue".  If you just want to read into a buffer, the standard way is to pass the buffer and its size into the function that is going to write to it.

Comment: The idiomatic way is to use something other then a `char *`. Something with value semantics so you can return by value, like `std::string`. The ugly solution is to use `new` to allocate the array and require the caller to free it once it's been used.

Comment: I do not see a return statement in case that the `for` never iterates or never uses the ´then`. What do you expect/intend the function to do in these cases?

Comment: Since we're also considering ugly solutions, you may consider just declaring `s` as static.  In a small program that is not going to execute in a multi-threaded environment, this will work.  It was good enough for various C library functions way back...  Although we all regret that.

Comment: You are creating the array on the stack, you want it on the heap: `char* s= new char[PIN_EPROM_STOP-PIN_EPROM_START+2];`. However, note that this means you need to control life time. If you don't want to use `std::string` for whatever reason, consider writing your own wrapper.

Comment: An option slightly less ugly than using `malloc` is to simply return `strdup(s)` (assuming that `s` is a properly null-terminated string), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60922107/10871073).

Comment: _"This function seems to work."_ contradicts  _"But the calling method gets back an empty string."_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments are probably going to lead you astray or at best confuse you.  Let me break it down with some options.

Firstly, the problem is as you say: the array whose address you are returning no longer exists when the function is popped off the stack to the caller.  Ignoring this results in Undefined Behavior.

Here are a few options, along with some discussion:

1. The caller owns the buffer

   ```
   void readFromFlashMemory(char *s, size_t len)
   ```

   Advantage is that the caller chooses how this memory is allocated, which is useful in embedded environments.

   Note you could also choose to return `s` from this function as a convenience, or to convey some extra meaning.

   For me, if I was working in an embedded environment such as Arduino, this would be my preference 100%.
2. Use `std::string`, `std::vector` or similar

   ```
   std::string readFromFlashMemory()
   ```

   This is probably the way you'd do it if you didn't care about allocation overhead and other potential issues such as fragmentation over time.
3. Allocate memory yourself

   ```
   char* readFromFlashMemory()
   ```

   If you want to ensure the allocated memory is exactly the right size, then you'd probably read into a local buffer first, and then allocate the memory and copy.  Same memory considerations as `std::string` or other solutions dealing with heap memory.

   This form also has the nightmarish property of the caller being responsible for managing the returned pointer and eventually calling `delete[]`.  It's highly inadvisable.  It's also distressingly common. :(
4. Better way to return dynamically allocated memory, if you absolutely must

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<char[]> readFromFlashMemory()
   ```

   Same as #3, but the pointer is managed safely.  Requires C++11 or later.
5. Use a static buffer

   ```
   const char* readFromFlashMemory()
   {
       static char s[FLASH_STOP_ADDR-FLASH_START_ADDR+2];
       // ...
       return s;
   }
   ```

   Generally frowned upon.  Particularly because this type of pattern results in nasty problems in multi-threaded environments.

   People mostly choose this approach because they're lazy and want a simple interface.  I guess one benefit is that the caller doesn't have to know anything about what size buffer is acceptable.
6. Make your own class with an internal buffer

   ```
   class FlashReader
   {
   public:
       const char* Read();
   private:
       char buffer[FLASH_STOP_ADDR-FLASH_START_ADDR+2];
   };
   ```

   This is more of a verbose solution, and may start to smell like over-engineering.  But it does combine the best parts of both #1 and #5.  That is, you get stack allocation of your buffer, you don't need to know the size, and the function itself doesn't need extra arguments.

   If you *did* want to have a static buffer, then you could just define one static instance of the class, but the difference would be a clear intent of this in the code.

Comment: I did #1. Thank you.

Comment: 5b) `static thread_local char s[FLASH_STOP_ADDR-FLASH_START_ADDR+2];` :-)